# Style in android could not be set up

Tags: android

I'm having a problem in setting up the activity as: setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
method cannot be resolved. 
can anyone help with it.
and yes I had already imported android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Comment: Can you please post your code for more clarity

Comment: There is no code problem. I just updated my studio and after that started a new project

Comment: import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Main_Activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar); // Error

Comment: As i mentioned in the answer,try using `AppCompatActivity` instead  of `Activity`

Comment: yeah .. thnx ... the problem was only that I needed to rewrite the AppComaptActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that setSupportActionBar() method cannot be resolved because you may have extended  AppBarActivity instead use.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
```

Answer (score 1):

Please verify that in your Activity you imported `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar`.

In addition verify your Activity inherits from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` since google has deprecated it.

Comment: No since the latest version it stopped inheriting from AppCompatActivity ... Now its working on Activity only

Comment: thnx .. i just needed to re write AppCompatActivity...after deleting once

Comment: Hey , the next time I run studio it has more errors than before... it saying Install repository and sync again but I'm unable to do so... I've updated the repository from extras too.....



and in Xml it showing AppBarLayout and Coordinator Layout class could not be found.

Comment: It was working all well before I updated to v1.4.1 .. but now it all error